# \hiderowcolors causes \noalign error

Tags: nicematrix, rowcolor, hline

Specifically

```
\hiderowcolors ->\noalign 
                  {\global \@rowcolorsfalse \@norowcolor }
```

This is my current code (edited to fit requirements). I started using NiceTabular because hlines would appear/disappear on pdf readers due to zooming and now I can't get it to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{float}

\title{Title example}
\author{}
\date{}

\definecolor{colorNALA}{HTML}{B70043}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EDEDED}
\definecolor{lavender}{HTML}{E8E2FF}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{lightgray} 
\centering
\begin{table}
\hiderowcolors\caption{Caption example}\\
\showrowcolors
\hline
\rowcolor{colorNALA}&\color{white}{column1}& \color{white}{column2}& \color{white}{column3}& \color{white}{column4}& \color{white}{column5}\\ \hline \endhead 
\hline
\hline \endfoot
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|l|c|c|c|c|}
0 & Text & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\

\hline
\hline
\rowcolor{lavender}&Total& 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
\rowcolor{lavender}&Total2&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{1}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Sketch of what it looked like without NiceTabular (aside from the font, obviously. This is temporary, I'll add the correct font in a sec). What I wanted from NiceTabular was for it to remove this zoom-dependent appearance of hlines.
[image]

Comment: don't show only a snippet with some "to fill in variables". Make  a proper, small, complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Edited!

Comment: Why are you using `\hline` etc. outside of a tabular?

Comment: Can you add a sketch of what the result should look like? That's not really obvious from your code.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz This was inherited from when I wasn't using NiceTabular. I tried removing the hlines, but the error persisted.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz added sketch

Comment: \hiderowcolors belongs *in* a tabular, you can't use it outside.

Comment: The code you provide leads to an error.
`./Sans-titre.tex:29: Misplaced \noalign.
\hiderowcolors ->\noalign 
                          {\global \@rowcolorsfalse \@norowcolor }
l.29 \hiderowcolors
                   \caption{Caption example}\\
?`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use tabular code like `\hline` etc outside of a tabular environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{float}

\title{Title example}
\author{}
\date{}

\definecolor{colorNALA}{HTML}{B70043}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EDEDED}
\definecolor{lavender}{HTML}{E8E2FF}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{lightgray} 
\centering
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Caption example}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|cl|c|ccc|}
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolor{lightgray}{1-}
\Body
 \hline
\rowcolor{colorNALA}&\color{white}{column1}& \color{white}{column2}& \color{white}{column3}& \color{white}{column4}& \color{white}{column5}\\ \hline 
0 & Text & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{lavender}&Total& 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\rowcolor{lavender}&Total2&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{1}\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suggest to have a look at the `tabularray` package. This makes it easy to configure which rows should have which colour etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\definecolor{colorNALA}{HTML}{B70043}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EDEDED}
\definecolor{lavender}{HTML}{E8E2FF}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|ll|c|ccc|},
  rows={bg=lightgray},
  row{1}={fg=white,bg=colorNALA},
  row{Y-Z}={bg=lavender}
}
\hline
\SetCell[c=2]{halign=c} column1 & & column2 & column3 & column4 & column5\\  
0 & Text & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
&Total& 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
&Total2& \SetCell[c=4]{} 1 &&&\\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\caption{Caption example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The spirit of the package `nicematrix` is to provide an environment `{NiceTabular}` which will work almost exactly as the classical `{tabular}` (of the package `array`) by default.

However, the package `nicematrix` also provides its own tools on some points (such as coloring the rows).

That's why I suggest the following code to construct your tabular with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Caption example}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|cl|c|ccc|}
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolor[HTML]{B70043}{1}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}{2}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E8E2FF}{3-}
\Body
    \Hline
    \RowStyle[color=white]{}
    &column1& column2& column3& column4& column5\\ 
    \Hline
    0 & Text & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \Hline
    &Total& 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    &Total2&\Block{1-4}{1}\\
    \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]